# Javascript bot giving 400 Bad Request after 30 successful tasks

Tags: javascript, bots

```
var startingID = 1000
function follow(id){ 
$.post('/user/follow', {targetUserID: id}, function(data){
if (data['success'] == false){
setTimeout(function(){follow(id + 1)}, 60000)
} else {
setTimeout(function(){follow(id + 1)}, 100)
}
})
}
follow(startingID)
```

I'm teaching myself JavaScript so I made this very basic bot as a beginner project, it follows people on a forum, similar to how you would follow someone on Twitter, however after following EXACTLY 30 people I get this in console:

```
GET --snipped link, its just an error page on the forum-- 400 (Bad Request)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's possible you're being rate limited by the bot. Without info on the server program I can't give you any additional info

Comment: What info would you need?